# Parsing a cell value as a row name in rbind()

Tags: r, rbind

I have two data `dfName` & `dfTest`.

```
> dfName <- c("Ball", "Cat", "Dog")
> dfName
[1] "Ball" "Cat"  "Dog"
```

I set name of first row of `dfTest` as "Apple",

```
> dfTest <- data.frame(t(1:3))
> rownames(dfTest) <- "Apple"
> dfTest
      X1 X2 X3
Apple  1  2  3
```

I want to append new rows to `dfTest` and assign its rows' name using `dfName`.

```
for(i in 1:3) {
  dfTest <- rbind(dfTest, dfName[i] = data.frame(t(1:3)))
}
```

But it will retun this error,

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"for(i in 1:3) {
  dfTest <- rbind(dfTest, dfName[i] ="
```

So I use `rownames` as workaround,

```
for(i in 1:3) {
  dfTest <- rbind(dfTest, data.frame(t(1:3)))
  rownames(dfTest)[i+1] <- dfName[i]
}
> dfTest
      X1 X2 X3
Apple  1  2  3
Ball   1  2  3
Cat    1  2  3
Dog    1  2  3
```

No issue if it's just a string variable,

```
> varA <- "Elephant"
> dfTest <- rbind(dfTest, varA = data.frame(t(1:3)))
> dfTest <- rbind(dfTest, "Flower" = data.frame(t(1:3)))
```

I know it's just one more line/function, but I wonder why I can't use `dfName[i]` in `rbind()`.

Edit: I can't use `rownames(dfTest) <- dfName` because their number of rows don't match in my actual data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834223/how-to-set-rownames-of-a-data-frame .

Comment: I would avoid using forloop to grow a dataframe object in a loop. Better to use `*apply` functions, then once the loop is complete, then add rownames for all at once. `rownames(dfTest)  <- myColNamesVector`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have have to set the names individually

Just use:

```
dfTest <- data.frame(matrix(1,3,4))

dfName <- c("Ball", "Cat", "Dog")

rownames(dfTest) <- dfName
```